# Html button does not download

Tags: python, html, download

I am working on a site where you can download python files. But When i add a python file to my html file it opens the code in a new tab instead of downloading.

This is my code

```
<a href="Test.py" download="Test.py"><button class="button"><span>Test File</span></button></a>
```

Comment: Probably a browser setting? Which browser are you using? I tried it in Chrome and it downloads the file. As an aside, if your `download` attribute is identical to your `href` attribute, you don't need the `download` value, just the `download` attribute keyword.

Comment: I tried your code in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. All of them downloaded (or prompted to download) the file.

Comment: I use Chrome but with all the code (also with the 3 answers) it opens the file instead of downloading it

Comment: Check your browser settings

Comment: Wich settings do I have to check?

Comment: Try this: hold Alt when you left click on your link. It should download instead of opening. Click the arrow next to the file name in the status bar. Is there an option that says, "Always download files of this type"?

Answer (score 0):

Your link should look like this:
`<a href="Test.py" download> ... </a>`

Notice the `download` attribute.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's syntax. It's just redundant. The `download` attribute accepts an argument if the file name is different than what the `href` specifies. If they are the same, no harm down.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've always used it that way, because in my opinion it doesn't make much sense to indicate the file to download in the attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `download` attribute to your link tag so it won't show your python file and it will directly download it so you code will look like this after adding this attribute :

```
<a href="Test.py" download><button class="button"><span>Test File</span></button></a>
```